# How to organize code for a Flask application with multiple set of templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm writing an application with Flask and I'd like to generate different code for desktop and mobile browsers. IMHO it should be a good idea to keep the application code identical and push the problem of serving different content down the stack at the template level - so it essentially becomes a matter of writing two sets of templates for the two use cases and finding a way to choose the correct one to use at every single request.
I'm using the default Jinja2 template engine with Flask.

I should mention that I have no experience with Flask and I'm learning my way through it while I write code - I'm taking this as an exercise too :)

What mechanism would you use to address this problem and keep source code as clean as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replying to myself :)

I ended up using this solution:

```
import flask
# patch flask.render_template()
_render_template = flask.render_template
def _my_render_template(*args, **kwargs):
    if detect_mobile_browser(flask.request.user_agent.string):
        args = ('m/' + args[0],) + args[1:]
    return _render_template(*args, **kwargs)
flask.render_template = _my_render_template
```

so far it seems to work, and I just put "mobile templates" in an `m/` subdirectory.

Comment: commenting to myself: this has also been briefly discussed on Flask mailing list: http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/11/7/serving-different-sets-of-templates-to-standard-and-mobile-browsers/

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point you in a probably somewhat different direction.

A lot of designers and developers (me included) don't see the future of website design in having the *templates* separated but in having one template which responds to its environment dynamically. That is it reorders its elements in a way that suites best for the given display.

It is called [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). I know that this is probably not the solution you have been looking for but it could become a way better one.

Comment: Yours is a good suggestion, broadly speaking, but not an answer to this specific question. I'd like to get to the point of having a single set of templates, with more-or-less "pure content", and doing all the styling and shuffling around with CSS3, but for the moment having two sets of templates is easier for us to manage. This will become a web app for our customers and more or less every page has a different template... too much for us CSS-ignorants to cope with!

Comment: Indeed. I just wanted to let you know since it sounds much like what you need.

Comment: Yeah, that *and* a (good) designer willing to work for food :) Seriously, thanks, I've bookmarked your link in our NOTES.txt. As I said, I wish someday to get there. A good idea could be to start with an (easier) fixed-width layout for the desktop browser, and use the mobile version to start building a fluid layout that'll eventually become the only one. But we're digressing from the question at hand.